# Validate a input with regular expression having specific condition

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I want to replace value of input to validate name of customer having following condition

1. Input can take alpha values
2. Input can take only special character like `' space
3. if there is adjacent set of `' or space then replace it by 1

like jone`'sfsd => jone`sfsd (remove later special character as two adjacent not allowed)
john   ket => john ket(remove 3 spaces with one)

I am currently able to fullfill case 1 and 2

my code

```js
$("#m").keyup(function() {
  var m = $("#m").val();
  m = m.replace(/[^a-z'`\s]/gi, '');
  m = m.replace(/[^\w\s]|(.)\1/gi, '');
  $("#m").val(m);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='m'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last `replace` line to

```
m = m.replace(/([^a-z])[^a-z]+/gi, '$1');
```

This matches two or special characters (since anything other than `a-z` is an allowed special character, from your first `replace`), captures the first one, and [replaces the match with the contents of the first capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#m").keyup(function() {
    var m = $("#m").val();
    m = m.replace(/[^a-z'`\s]/gi, '');
    m = m.replace(/([^a-z])[^a-z]+/gi, '$1');
    $("#m").val(m);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='m'>
```